# an adjective for "to take pleasure"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am a translator looking for the right word in English for the Spanish word "gozoso." It is an adjective connected to the Spanish verb "gozar" or to take pleasure. It differs from the less sexually charged Spanish word "disfrutar," which means enjoy.  Something related to revelry might work...Any ideas? Many thanks!
The phrase in Spanish, if it helps, is "...en la  irrupción permanente de otras formas de vida, distintas, desordenadas, ásperas y gozosas, en las batallas que nos quedan para defender el consumo y la fiesta"

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example sentence please?

Comment: Have you checked the thesaurus under "enjoyable" or "pleasurable"?

Comment: Gozar translates to a word in english.  sSearch dictionary/synonyms/thesaurus. Edit your question and present those possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a level up from 'enjoy' then how about to 'delight' in something? Delight can certainly relate to revelry, and can also be erotic and sensual:

'She delighted in the rich taste of the ruby red wine'
'She delighted in his warm kisses'

Delight signifies a high level of pleasure which is heartful, and it also has a light uplifting feel about it.

Another good word is rapture - to be 'in raptures' over something means, kind of, exclaiming over its great and wonderful qualities, to be both enjoying it and extolling its virtues at the same time. A kind of 'active enjoyment', a great deal of enjoyment, passion.

Passion is another word you could use, demoting a deep sense of involvement with a person thing or idea.

Lastly, joy is a feeling often connected with taking pleasure.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/delight

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions (all adjectival):

- titillating
- libidinous
- lascivious
- erotic
- sensual
- epicurean
- hedonic
- stimulating
- arousing
- orgiastic
- voluptuous